# Unexpected results when trying to amplify voltage across a wheatstone bridge

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, amplifier, wheatstone-bridge

I am working on a project, and am trying to amplify the voltage across wheatstone bridge. Here is the diagram:

[image: Wheatstone bridge to amplifier]

where \$R_1 = 1,000 \Omega\$

\$R_3 = 10,000 \Omega\$

and \$R_2\$ is a potentiometer, set so that the voltage across the bridge is 10 mV

The gain of the amplifier is simply \$R_3/R_1 = 10\$, so I expect an output voltage at \$V_{out}\$ of 1V.

I do not see 1V out, I see somewhere around 1.5V, and I am certain that whatever the problem is has something to do with the fact that the voltage across my bridge doesn't stay at 10mV when connected to the amplifier. When I connect the bridge to the two leftmost op amps, and check the voltage across the bridge again, it is around 45mV.

Why is this? I've checked my amplifier circuit with classmates and rebuilt it several times, I can't tell what might be wrong. What might be causing such an issue?

Comment: You have proper +/-V supply rails to the opamp, not just +5 and GND? Or is it a rail-to-rail opamp?

Comment: It's an LM324N opamp, one lead takes a positive voltage and one goes to ground, which is how I have it configured.

Comment: @jphollowed Not to belabor Brian's point, but is the *correct* one going to ground (pin 11) and the *correct* one (pin 4) going to +5? (numbers refer to DIP or SOIC packages). If so, are the grounds the same, and what is the voltage on each input wrt ground?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yea the are correct

Comment: Have you accounted for the non-ideality of the your op-amps? Those are BJT input stage op-amps and thus will have input bias currents as well as having offsets on the outputs. You should be able to systematically determine where the difference is coming from by changing up connections and shorting leads together and seeing how things diverge from expectation.

Comment: **Assuming** you've got the inputs hooked up right, and **assuming** the bridge is not in the meg ohm range, maybe the LM324 is toast.

Comment: Did you hook up the 4th op-amp in the '324 package to avoid oscillations?

Comment: **As Drawn** you are not establishing the input voltage to the opamps, the 5v bridge excitation and the amps do not share a common ground. If the bridge excitation is really floating with respect to the amplifier supplies, then the amplifier input bias current will take the amp inputs to their rails. Sharing bridge -ve with amp -ve should fix that. As an unrelated observation (this will not solve the bias current problem if you have it), for 3 extra resistors, you could make a much *better* differential input amplifier. Look up 'instrumentation amplifier' on wikipedia.

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks, the op amp and the bridg weren't sharing a common ground. I put them on a con mom ground, and played around a bit, but it's working now, so that may have been the fix

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you expect 1V out, with a 10 mV input and a gain of 10. Personally, I would expect something closer to 100 mV, but in any case, 1.5 V is obviously wrong.

The LM324 *should* be capable of driving the output to 0V. However, what it can't do is drive the output negative. Are you sure your bridge is unbalanced in the direction that will drive the output positive — left side higher than right side?

Some opamps have the property that they invert the output when the input stage is driven too hard into saturation. I don't recall offhand if the LM324 has this problem, but it could explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I fixed it. You're right trust i should not have expected a 1 v output, but rather a 0.1v. I discovered that the op amp for some reason will not output below 0.5v, I'm the amplifier configuration i am using. I changed my resistance ratio by using some 220 ohm resistors, and now have a gain of 40, and changed my input voltage to ~30mV. I also made the op amp and bridge share a common ground, which they weren't doing originally

Answer (score 0):

The LM324 inputs draw a bias current, albeit very small. Unless the bridge supply and amplifiers have a connection (your diagram shows one floating with respect to the other) then the bias current will pull the inputs right up to the top rail, out of the permitted input range, and your amplifiers will stop working as amplifiers.

As the bridge outputs are nominally 2.5v, and that is a valid input level for LM324s, connecting the opamp and bridge grounds should be sufficient.